# How to use na.locf with time limits to avoid filling across market close?

Tags: r

I am working with futures contracts which close at 4 PM or 16:00 Central Time and re-open at 5 PM or or possibly later. I can filter the data for when it is closed, but when I do na.locf it still fills in data from 4 PM on.

Here is a small example and how I generated the xts data including 2 days:

```
days1 <- c("2017-05-05 15:58","2017-05-05 15:59","2017-05-05 16:00","2017-05-05 17:01","2017-05-05 17:02","2017-05-05 17:03","2017-05-05 17:04","2017-05-05 17:05")
test2 = xts(as.numeric(c(24,23,22,"NA","30","NA",31,"31")),order.by = as.POSIXct(days1, tz = "America/Chicago"))
test2 = xts(as.numeric(c(24,23,22,"NA","30","NA",31,"31")),order.by = as.POSIXct(days1, tz = "America/Chicago"))
t1 <- cbind(test1,test2)
t2 <- t1
index(t2) = index(t1)+(60*60*24)
DF <-rbind(t1,t2)
colnames(DF) <- c("Bid","Ask")

> DF
                    Bid Ask
2017-05-05 15:58:00  23  24
2017-05-05 15:59:00  22  23
2017-05-05 16:00:00  20  22
2017-05-05 17:01:00  NA  NA
2017-05-05 17:02:00  NA  30
2017-05-05 17:03:00  25  NA
2017-05-05 17:04:00  26  31
2017-05-05 17:05:00  NA  31
2017-05-06 15:58:00  23  24
2017-05-06 15:59:00  22  23
2017-05-06 16:00:00  20  22
2017-05-06 17:01:00  NA  NA
2017-05-06 17:02:00  NA  30
2017-05-06 17:03:00  25  NA
2017-05-06 17:04:00  26  31
2017-05-06 17:05:00  NA  31
```

And the desired result on the new data.

```
                    Bid Ask
2017-05-05 15:58:00  23  24
2017-05-05 15:59:00  22  23
2017-05-05 16:00:00  20  22
2017-05-05 17:01:00  NA  NA
2017-05-05 17:02:00  NA  30
2017-05-05 17:03:00  25  30
2017-05-05 17:04:00  26  31
2017-05-05 17:05:00  26  31
2017-05-06 15:58:00  23  24
2017-05-06 15:59:00  22  23
2017-05-06 16:00:00  20  22
2017-05-06 17:01:00  NA  NA
2017-05-06 17:02:00  NA  30
2017-05-06 17:03:00  25  30
2017-05-06 17:04:00  26  31
2017-05-06 17:05:00  26  31
```

I updated the sample data with an xts object. I am sure there is an easier and faster way to make one, but that would be another question.

Normal na.locf will fill the na's at 17:01 and 17:02 which would result in bad data. But filling the data past 17:00 is perfectly fine.

I don't think maxgap would work as I might not have a small gap, and still not want to fill.

I can see two ways of doing this. One is to have na.locf not fill if the difference in time-stamps is greater than one hour.
Or it may be even better to simply never fill past a certain time such as 16:00 in this case.

This should be fast so I would like to avoid any loops such as spiting the data by days and then re-merging unless it is with a quick vectorized method.

I would also be ok with an Rcpp solution if it can correctly handle the timestamps.
**Update:**
This is my rcpp code which works where the differance between rows is beyond a threshold.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix naLocf(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& DataMatrix, int maxDiffSeconds = 0)
{
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix res = clone(DataMatrix);
  Rcpp::NumericVector Index = res.attr("index");
  int numRow = res.nrow();
  int numCol = res.ncol();
  for (int ii = 1;ii<numRow;ii++)
  {
    if(maxDiffSeconds == 0 || Index(ii)-Index(ii-1) < maxDiffSeconds)
    {
      for (int jj = 0;jj<numCol;jj++)
      {
        if(Rcpp::NumericMatrix::is_na(res(ii,jj)))
        {
          res(ii,jj) = res(ii-1,jj); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

And to execute:

```
DF2 = naLocf(DF,60*60)
```

It works because the xts index is a number in seconds from 1970-01-01. So if the difference is beyond the values of 3600 or one hour, I don't replace the NAs.

As far as part 2 the time specific stop at "16:00" can basically done with GMT the time value is direct so the time value modulo 86400 and 16:00 is 57600 of the remainder.
But with different time zones, the time value changes, but by different amounts based on daylight savings so I have been unable to get a consistent time to work.

Comment: have you tried splitting the data in two parts, one part before 16:00, and one after 16:00, then use `na.locf` in the part that you want and then `rbind` them ?

Comment: Not really an Rcpp question so I'll remove that tag.

Comment: I have split the data, but only with a loop into lists, so it is slow. And I use locf after merging data sets so it needs to be done every time so it makes it even slower.

Answer (score 1):

**1) data.frame** Create a grouping variable `g` and perform the na.locf separately on each group of rows separately.

```
library(zoo)

g <- DF$time > "16:00:00"
replace(DF, -1, do.call("rbind", by(DF[-1], g, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

giving:

```
      time  A  B
1 15:58:00 23 24
2 15:59:00 22 23
3 16:00:00 20 22
4 17:01:00 NA NA
5 17:02:00 NA 30
6 17:03:00 25 30
7 17:04:00 26 31
8 17:05:00 26 31
```

**2) data.table** If speed is an issue try data.table using `g` from above:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, cbind(.SD[, 1], na.locf(.SD)[, -1]), by = g][, -1]
```

**3) zoo series** With zoo objects it simplifies:

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = times)  # test input

g <- time(z) > "16:00:00"
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(z, g), na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
```

**3a)** Another way to do this using `z` is the following.

```
pre4 <- time(z) <= "16:00:00"
rbind( na.locf(z[pre4, ], na.rm = FALSE),
       na.locf(z[!pre4, ], na.rm = FALSE))
```

**3b)** or using `pre4` from above:

```
zz <- z
zz[pre4, ] <- na.locf(z[pre4, ], na.rm = FALSE)
zz[!pre4, ] <- na.locf(z[!pre4, ], na.rm = FALSE)
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
time       A    B
15:58:00   23   24
15:59:00   22   23
16:00:00   20   22
17:01:00   NA   NA
17:02:00   NA   30
17:03:00   25   NA
17:04:00   26   31
17:05:00   NA   31"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: It works as shown, but I cannot get it to work on my actual data where it is the an XTS object. I filter xts using DF["2017-12-03 17:00/2017-12-04 16:00"] which gives me only the day and time needed, but I cannot get the xts to take "16:00:00" or "16:00" or "T16:00 and get it to work from your example. Thank you.

Comment: You can't have a times only series in xts.  I have added (3) which shows how to do it with a zoo object.

Comment: Thank you. I still could not get it to work. I believe my issue is that time(z) did not work. To help, I updated the question with an XTS time series for the sample data and the desired result. Hopefully this will help better explain my problems. Thank you again.